# Complex Numbers, finding exact value without calculator

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I do apologize about the formatting, I wish I could figure out how to, at least I tried.

I want to know how I can find the principal argument of $z$,  where 
$$z=\frac{1-\sqrt3i}{-1+i}$$ 
without a calculator.

I times the top and the bottom by the conjugate of the denominator.
Then I was left with $$\frac{-1-\sqrt3-i+\sqrt3i}{2}.$$
Then I got 
$$\tan^{-1}\left[\frac{-i+\sqrt3i}{-1-\sqrt3i}\right].$$
I don't know where to go from after this step nor if this step is even right.

Thank you, any link on the formatting guide would also be appreciated.
This is all tech-free.

Comment: Here a link on formatting: meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: can you use $\LaTeX$ please?

Comment: Why did my formatting not work?

Comment: is it $$z=\frac{1-\sqrt{3}i}{-1+i}$$?

Comment: yes it is that one

Comment: You forgot a "\" before the "sqrt" - it should  be \sqrt{} - note that the curly brackets are important. Also, right now you have chosen to render your math as code, which you have to delete first.

Comment: Use `$z=\frac{1-\sqrt3i}{-1+i}$` to show $z=\frac{1-\sqrt3i}{-1+i}$. Do not use the back quotes `. That is for literal code, not formatting. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use exponential form:
$$1-\sqrt 3\mathrm i=2\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{\mathrm i\pi}3},\qquad -1+\mathrm i=\sqrt2\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\mathrm 3 i\pi}4}=\sqrt2\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{\mathrm 5 i\pi}4} $$
whence $$z=\sqrt 2\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\mathrm 11 i\pi}{12}},\quad \arg z=\frac{11\pi}{12}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You have to carry the actual division:

$$\frac{1-\sqrt3\,i}{-1+i}=-\frac{1-\sqrt3\,i}{1-i}\cdot\frac{1+i}{1+i}=-\frac{(1+\sqrt3)+(1-\sqrt3)i}2$$

and then the argument is

$$\arctan\left(-\frac{1-\sqrt3}{1+\sqrt3}\right)=\arctan\left(\sqrt3-2\right)$$

Comment: Answer says 11*pi/12

Comment: That seems to be right.

Comment: How can you actually get there without a calculator?

Comment: @P.Andrews I honestly can't say of the top of my head. Perhaps playing a little with some trigonometric identities.

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this is by using De Moivre's theorem. With z convert the numerator and denominator into polar form, then use De Moivre's theorem to divide the resultant. In case you aren't used to cis(theta). cis(theta) represents cos(theta) + i*sin(theta), . Therefore z=(r1cis(theta))/(r2cis(alpha)). We now follow De Moivre's theorem's rule for division, the resultant of the example becomes z=(r1/r2)cis(theta-alpha). It is actually immensely hard to do this in Cartesian form, I assume you may have to shift trig identities around a lot. In the question I asked the answer becomes $$\sqrt{2}cis(\frac{-13pi}{12})$$
Which in the principal domain is $$\sqrt{2}cis(\frac{11pi}{12})$$